# What is required for commenting in someone's question

Tags: support

I am trying to comment on people's question but there is no such option of doing so. Do I need higher reputation ? If yes then how much?

Answer (score 3):

You need [50 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) to comment everywhere

See also: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 2):

I see you are at 46 rep points, so what you need to do is to post an well thought out post, demonstrating what you have found so far on the particular topic with a clear and interesting question, and hope someone upvotes it.

Comment: Thanks.I understood.

Comment: excellent, I look forward to your contribution!